# Help needed with the most trivial protobuf-net example 2

Tags: .net, protobuf-net

Observe the following code (taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107832/help-needed-with-the-most-trivial-protobuf-net-example)):

```
  [ProtoContract]
  public class B
  {
    [ProtoMember(1)] public int Y;
  }

  [ProtoContract]
  public class C
  {
    [ProtoMember(1)] public int Y;
  }

  class Program
  {
    static void Main()
    {
      object b = new B { Y = 2 };
      object c = new C { Y = 4 };
      using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
      {
        Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(ms, b, PrefixStyle.Base128);
        Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(ms, c, PrefixStyle.Base128);
        ms.Position = 0;
        var b2 = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<B>(ms, PrefixStyle.Base128);
        Debug.Assert(((B)b).Y == b2.Y);
        var c2 = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<C>(ms, PrefixStyle.Base128);
        Debug.Assert(((C)c).Y == c2.Y);
      }
    }
  }
```

Obviously, the code is wrong, because `b` and `c` are declared as `object`, but I serialize them using the generic `Serializer.Serialize<T>` method:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException occurred
  Message=Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index
  Source=protobuf-net
  ParamName=index
  StackTrace:
       at ProtoBuf.Meta.BasicList.Node.get_Item(Int32 index)
  InnerException:
```

Everything works fine if I redeclare `b` as `B` and `c` as `C`. However, I need them to be declared as `object`, so I guess I have to serialize them using the non generic method `Serializer.NonGeneric.SerializeWithLengthPrefix`, the problem I do not understand the meaning of the extra `fieldNumber` argument expected by the method. Can someone explain what is it and how should I use it here?

I use protobuf-net v2.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I have managed to make it work with the addition of the following code:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(object), false).AddSubType(1, typeof(B)).AddSubType(2, typeof(C));
```

Although it works, the problem is that I need to know at compile time the types used in the serialization (B = 1, C = 2), which is bad for me. Is there a better way?

**EDIT2**

OK, I have changed the code like so:

```
public class GenericSerializationHelper<T> : IGenericSerializationHelper
{
  void IGenericSerializationHelper.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(Stream stream, object obj, PrefixStyle prefixStyle)
  {
    Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(stream, (T)obj, prefixStyle);
  }
}

public interface IGenericSerializationHelper
{
  void SerializeWithLengthPrefix(Stream stream, object obj, PrefixStyle prefixStyle);
}

...

static void Main()
{
  var typeMap = new Dictionary<Type, IGenericSerializationHelper>();
  typeMap[typeof(B)] = new GenericSerializationHelper<B>();
  typeMap[typeof(C)] = new GenericSerializationHelper<C>();

  object b = new B { Y = 2 };
  object c = new C { Y = 4 };
  using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    typeMap[b.GetType()].SerializeWithLengthPrefix(ms, b, PrefixStyle.Base128);
    typeMap[c.GetType()].SerializeWithLengthPrefix(ms, c, PrefixStyle.Base128);
    ms.Position = 0;
    var b2 = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<B>(ms, PrefixStyle.Base128);
    Debug.Assert(((B)b).Y == b2.Y);
    var c2 = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<C>(ms, PrefixStyle.Base128);
    Debug.Assert(((C)c).Y == c2.Y);
  }
}
```

Now, in order to serialize the objects I do not need any compile time mapping, I just jump to the respective generic method. Of course, I understand that in this scheme I must know the types at deserialization, which is still a bummer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are serializing homogeneous data, the field-number is largely irrelevant, with the minor caveat that keeping it as 1 (aka `Serializer.ListItemTag`) it is trivial to read it back as a list if you want (but pretty easy either way).

In the case of heterogeneous data, as in this example - there is a non-generic API designed for this purpose (in fact, in v2 *all* the APIs are non-generic - the generic API simply forwards to the non-generic). By passing in a `TypeResolver`, you can tell it *on the fly* how to interpret any tag encountered (at the root of the stream). If you choose to return `null` for a given tag, it assumes you aren't interested in that object and skips it entirely (in the example below it will just blow up, obviously - but that is just because the example code is minimal):

```
// I'm giving the example in terms of the v2 API, because there is a bug in the 
// Serializer.NonGeneric code in the beta - simply, in the first beta cut this
// doesn't correctly forward to the type-model. This will be fixed ASAP.
TypeModel model = RuntimeTypeModel.Default;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    var tagToType = new Dictionary<int, Type>
    {  // somewhere, we need a registry of what field maps to what Type
        {1, typeof(B)}, {2, typeof(C)}
    };
    var typeToTag = tagToType.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Value, pair => pair.Key);

    object b = new B { Y = 2 };
    object c = new C { Y = 4 };
    // in v1, comparable to Serializer.NonGeneric.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(ms, b, PrefixStyle.Base128, typeToTag[b.GetType()]);
    model.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(ms, b, null, PrefixStyle.Base128, typeToTag[b.GetType()]);
    model.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(ms, c, null, PrefixStyle.Base128, typeToTag[c.GetType()]);
    ms.Position = 0;

    // in v1, comparable to Serializer.NonGeneric.TryDeserializeWithLengthPrefix(ms, PrefixStyle.Base128, key => tagToType[key], out b2);
    object b2 = model.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix(ms, null, null, PrefixStyle.Base128, 0, key => tagToType[key]);
    object c2 = model.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix(ms, null, null, PrefixStyle.Base128, 0, key => tagToType[key]);

    Assert.AreEqual(((B)b).Y, ((B)b2).Y);
    Assert.AreEqual(((C)c).Y, ((C)c2).Y);
}
```

Comment: I have to grok it all still. Thanks.